# Ubuntu server remote desktop blank screen

Tags: rdp

I have a (PC) server running Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS

Things were running fine until I removed (complete uninstall) OpenBox and Lightweight LXDE for trying other desktops. Now the server boots fine but shows no log screen and among the messages at boot time shows:

Stopping LigthDM Display Manager

And stays there until rebooted

On the other hand, when I connect via RDP (using windows remote desktop) the log screen shows, accepts the user and password and shows some kind of blank screen and nothing else. I’ve tried to reinstall (using putty connections) OpenBox and LXDE (vanilla) but the results are the same. Maybe when the packages were purged some configuration was erased but I’m lost here How can I restore LXDE as it was the default desktop (at least for the remote connections)?

How can I make the initial login screen reappear?

Answer (score 2):

I issued

```
echo "lxsession -s LXDE -e LXDE" >~/.xsession
```

and it was back in business also with RDP